# hex value (0x21AF) set in ByteData in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var i=23FF;
```

how to convert this
convert `i` value in hex value like `0x23FF`

```
ByteData mssg = ByteData(12);
      mssg.setUint16(5, 0x23FF);
```

How I set hex value in `ByteData`

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final hexString = myInteger.toRadixString(16);      // 7e4
```

Convert it into `String` and `count` the number of places.

```
final paddedString = hexString.padLeft(count, '0x');     // 0x7e4
```

Decimal to Hex

```
String hex = 2020.toRadixString(16).padLeft(4, '0');
print(hex); // 07e4
```

Decimal to Binary (ByteData)

```
String binary = 2020.toRadixString(2);
print(binary); // 11111100100
```

Hex to Binary (ByteData)

```
String binary = hex.toRadixString(2);
print(binary); // 11111100100
```

Comment: hex value (0xFFA4) in ByteData how

Comment: Actually, my requirement is    to store value like this   mssg.setUint16(5, 0x23FF);
but when i convert  int.toRadixString(16) i get value in sting variable . so string variable is not allow to set in mssg.setUint16(5, 0x23FF);

Comment: Is array allowed? or tell me which format is? Are you trying to transmit data, If yes then use dart convert.. http://devoncarew.github.io/papyrus.dart/dart.convert.html   or    https://www.bezkoder.com/dart-base64-image/